# How do I offset a String() in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, string, for-loop, foreach, offset

I have a series of files in a directory that I want to iterate through, but I need to be able to start at a specific file in the list and it is not necessarily the first item in the string(). If I have the String() {"a","b","c","d"} and I want to iterate through each one but start at c,b, or d instead of a, how do I accomplish this using a For Each item in ....
NOTE: However the solution goes it must be able to handle different numbers of items in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: What  specific file in the list and what `String()`? What have you tried?

Comment: NOTE: If I start at "b","c", or "d", I MUST be able to iterate through all items in the list n matter what, I just want to start at a different item other than index 0. If I start at index 3, I MUST be able to iterate through index 0,1 and 2 as well.

Comment: where it starts is a setting of the application. I iterate through this list multiple times, I just need it to be able to start where it left off(This is a scheduling program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. `For Each`-ing over an array will always enumerate from the first to the last item.

You can implement this behavior yourself, of course.

```
    Dim myArray As String() = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}
    Dim offset As Integer = 2

    For i As Integer = offset To UBound(myArray)
        Dim item As String = myArray(i)
        ' Do things
        Console.WriteLine(item)
    Next
    If Not offset = 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To offset - 1
            Dim item As String = myArray(i)
            ' Do things
            Console.WriteLine(item)
        Next
    End If

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Would go through (offset, offset+1, offset+2.... offset+(n-offset-1), 0, 1, 2 ... offset-1).
Might be some mistakes, my VB is rusty.

Comment: Thus does not work as I get ERROR: SystemArgumentOutOfRange when specifying an offset other than 0 and the code is off as well. Both of the "loop" should be "Next" and this doesn't work for a string().

Comment: Sorry about that, I did say my VB was rusty :P.
I fired up VS and wrote some that worked.
Output: `c d e a b`. I reflected the new code in my answer.